# How to optimize this Ruby code that fetches web content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have a Rails 3.2.12 app that fetches data from a partner API by making POST requests. However, we're finding that our code seems to be a bottleneck, as it takes longer to process requests than expected. Can we do anything to speed up the code?

Should we use another XML parser? Is there a faster way to post SSL requests in Ruby?

Thanks!

```
def ced( ad )
    # Set vars
    u = 'e'
    pw = 'p'
    ad = ad.join ','
    url = 'https://r.e.com/interface.asp?ResponseType=XML&Command=BC' + '&UID=' + u + '&PW=' + pw + '&DL=' + ad
    results = []

    # Invoke API command
    uri = URI.parse url
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    resp = http.request req

    # Parse API response
    resp_xml = Nokogiri.XML resp.body
    resp_xml.remove_namespaces!
    num_errors = resp_xml.at_xpath('//ErrCount').content

    # Any errors?
    if num_errors != '0'
        error = true

    # No errors, process domains
    else
        resp_xml.xpath('//CheckResult').each do |elem|
            results << {
            :domain => elem.xpath('D').text.downcase,
            :status => case elem.xpath('RRPCode').text
                when '210' then 'a'
                when '211' then 't'
                else
                    error = true
                    'error'
                end
            }
        end
    end

    <truncated>
end
```

Comment: Benchmark the code.  See if the POST request is slow or if it's your XML parsing.  Without knowing which, it's hard to say how to optimize.

Comment: Thanks, is there a recommended way to benchmark, or should we just put Time statements between the POST and XML parsing?

Comment: Spitting out time statements would be the simplest and may identify the problem.  Otherwise you'll need to use something like the Benchmark class and save the results over time to analyze.

Comment: ok, thanks @PhilipHallstrom. actually it seems like this code block finishes in < 1 sec, but for some reason the response doesn't get back to our client for about 5-6 seconds. is it normal for rails to add this much overhead?

Comment: That whole block of code returns in < 1 sec?  But your client (ie. web browser?) doesn't see it for 5-6 seconds?  That's not normal.  Which means somewhere else in your code you've got a delay.  Happy hunting!

Comment: nokogiri uses libxml2 as the library which is great in its performances.i don't see a need for another xml parser

Comment: ok thanks all! we need to hunt down this bottleneck. :)

Comment: actually one more quick question: we're making 5 calls to the same API URL in succession (API can only take X elements at once so we need to break things into 5 calls). should we use the same Net::HTTP object? or is it okay to call this block 5x as we're doing here?

Comment: Have you considered background jobs ?